# Unable to Load Gallery Images With 'foreach' command

Tags: php, session-variables

I've put together the following script which allows users to view their uploaded images in the original folder structure that they were saved.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
        <?php session_start(); 

$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['locationid']=$_POST['locationid'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<?php 
  //This variable specifies relative path to the folder, where the gallery with uploaded files is located.
  $galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/' . $_SESSION['locationid'] . '/';

  //let's DEBUG the above assignment 
  if (!is_dir($galleryPath)) { die("No folder exists at $galleryPath!"); } 

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath); 

  //let's DEBUG this one too 
  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath)) { die("No folder exists at $absGalleryPath!"); } 

  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0');

   // DEBUG: let's check for the XML while we're at it 
  //if (!file_exists($absGalleryPath.'files.xml')) { die("No XML found at $absGalleryPath"."files.xml"); } 
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . '/' . 'files.xml'); 


  $items = array();

  for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) {
    $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i);
    $path = $xmlFile->getAttribute('name');
    $path = explode('/', $path);

    $t = &$items;
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($path); $j++) {
      if (empty($t[$path[$j]])) {
        $t[$path[$j]] = array();
      }
      $t = &$t[$path[$j]];
    }
    $t['/src/'] = $xmlFile->getAttribute('source');
    $t['description'] = $xmlFile->getAttribute('description');
    $t['size'] = $xmlFile->getAttribute('size');
  }

  $basePath = empty($_GET['path']) ? '' : $_GET['path'];
  if ($basePath) {
    $basePath = explode('/', $basePath);
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($basePath); $j++) {
      $items = &$items[$basePath[$j]];
    }
  }

  $files = array();
  $dirs = array();


  function urlpartencode(&$item, $index) {
    $item = rawurlencode($item);
  }

  foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value['/src/'])) {
      $value['/src/'] = explode('/', $value['/src/']);
      array_walk($value['/src/'], 'urlpartencode');
      $value['/src/'] = implode('/', $value['/src/']);
      $files[] = array(
        'name' => $key,
        'src' => $value['/src/'],
        'description' => htmlentities($value['description'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'),
        'size' => htmlentities($value['size'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
      ); 
    } else {
      $dirs[] = $key;
    }
  }

  $basePath = empty($_GET['path']) ? '' : $_GET['path'];
  $up = dirname($basePath);
  if ($up == '.') {
    $up = '';
  }

  sort($files);
  sort($dirs);
?>
<head>
  <title>View Image Folders</title> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="Libraries/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -50px;
}

-->
  </style>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; margin-right: 160px; margin-left: -180px;">
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "index.php" /> Add Images <a/> &rarr; <a href = "javascript:document.imagefolders.submit()"> View All Images </a> </div>
<form id="imagefolders" name="imagefolders" class="page" action="gallery.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">  
   <div id="container">
  </div>
    <div id="center">
      <div class="aB">
        <div class="aB-B">
          <?php if ('Uploaded files' != $current['title']) :?>
          <?php endif;?>
          <div class="demo">
          <input name="username" type="hidden" id="username" value="IRHM73" />
          <input name="locationid" type="hidden" id="locationid" value="1" /> 
            <div class="inner">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="gallery">
                  <table class="gallery-link-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                      <tr class="head">
                        <th class="col-name">
                          Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="col-size">
                          Size
                        </th>
                        <th class="col-description">
                          Description
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                      <tr class="directory odd">
                        <td class="col-name">
                          <a href="?path=<?php echo rawurlencode($up); ?>">..</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-size">
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-description">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <?php $i = 1; ?>

                      <?php foreach ($dirs as $dir) : ?>
                      <tr class="directory <?php $i++; echo ($i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'); ?>">
                        <td><a href="?path=<?php echo rawurlencode(($basePath ? $basePath . '/' : '') . $dir); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dir, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
                        <td>Folder</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>

                      <?php foreach ($files as $file) : ?>
                      <tr class="<?php $i++; echo ($i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'); ?>">
                        <td><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $galleryPath . $file['src']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($file['name'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($file['size'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($file['description'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can correctly show the folders, but when I click on the folder to drill down to the individual images I receive the following error:

`Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/UploadedFiles/files.xml" in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/imagefolders.php on line 25 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/imagefolders.php on line 65`

Line 25 is this line `$descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . '/' . 'files.xml'); and line 65 is this:`foreach ($items as $key => $value) {`

My initial script didn't use session variables and I didn't have any issues. However I now need to include these, so I'm sure that there is a conflict between these and the `foreach` command. I've done quite a bit of research to see if anyone else has had similar issues, but can't find anything.

I just wondered whether someone could look at this and let me know where I'm gong wrong.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: oh, question is too long. Ask essential stuff.

Comment: @webbandit, hi, I've now shortened my post a little. I was just concerned about not providing enough information. Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Error 1

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/UploadedFiles/files.xml"
```

The Origin of the Problem is `$descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . '/' . 'files.xml');`

It is bad practice trying to load file you are not sure it exists or is readable

Something like this is better and make sure you catch exception

```
$file = $absGalleryPath . '/' . 'files.xml' ;
if(!is_readable($file) || !file_exists($file))
{
 throw new Exception("Missing XML File");
}
```

### Error 2

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/imagefolders.php on line 65
```

A. Since you are not able to load the first `xml` document ... trying to continue the process would result to this error

B. `foreach ($items as $key => $value) {` so it would run independently where it is populated or not

C. Too many Referencing would make your code more difficult to understand and debug ...

### Conclusion

I think you should post the content of `files.xml`  you would be surprised it innovative solutions and ore effective code people would come up with

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. My requirements have slightly changed since I posted the original question. However, the solution you posted has helped with this. Kind regards

Comment: Can you add sample of the xml file you are loading ... i don't want to miss anything ...

Comment: Hi @Baba, many thanks for your help on this. Since I added the initial post my requirements changed, and I decided to scrap the 'folders' aspect of the image upload. But you were awarded the Bounty for your time, trouble and help.

Comment: Thanks .... I really appreciate .... Do you still have issues with the gallery system ??? If you still having issues let me know so that I can assist ... Thanks

Comment: put the entire script it pastbin .. i"ll look at it line by line and see what i can do

Comment: Hi @Baba, sorry ignore my earlier comment, I pressed the wrong button. As I said, yes I do still have the initial problems with viewing the images. However I wouldn't be comfortable in you spending anymore time on this. I have come up with a workaround which mitigates the need for the images to be stored in individual folders.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` is about your `foreach ($items as $key => $value)`. So place `var_dump($items);` before that foreach to see full dump of `items` variable. Seems like it's not even an array.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to help me uut. I've added the line as you suggested, which incidentally, is really clever and I receive the following: `stags-snow_1544533c.jpg"]=> &array(3) { ["/src/"]=> string(23) "stags-snow_1544533c.jpg" ["description"]=> string(23) "No description provided" ["size"]=> string(5) "21341" } } }` From a beginners perspective, it seems as if the array is working, but I'm not really sure about what to do next. Could you perhaps elaborate please? Kind regards

Comment: `stags-snow_1544533c.jpg"]=> &array(3) { ["/src/"]=> string(23) "stags-snow_1544533c.jpg" ["description"]=> string(23) "No description provided" ["size"]=> string(5) "21341" } } }` looks like an corect array (you have taken not all it's dump). Now it's time to add `var_dump($dirs);` and `var_dump($files);` before applying `foreach` on them. Show  dumped data here.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your continued help with this. I've added the lines as you suggested and they both come back as `NULL`. I think I'm correct in saying that it suggests that nothing is being passed to the variables? Could you tell me please do you think that this is because I'm using Session Variables to create my filepath? Please be aware that I've updated my script a little and have replaced the one shown in my original post with this.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to bother you with another post, but I've found put what the problem is, although I admit, I'm not sure what the solution is. I've done some more testing and looked at these lines `$galleryPath` and `$absGalleryPath`. If I changed them to this `$galleryPath= 'UploadedFiles/' . 'IRHM73' . '/' . '1' . '/'; $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;` changing the `$_SESSION['username']` and `$_SESSION[locationid]` with the values, I can get the script to work. It's strange though because I've echoed the variables and they're being pulled through ok. Kind regards

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not because I was unable to get the script working when passing the session variables into the file path. Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. your foreach loop is not getting properdata as you are willing to do..pls use `var_dump` to check data you are getting.
2. check out path for your `XML`.